# SSIS using XML and using exiSt DB

Tags: xml

Would you please help me in wriritng simple student information system using XML??
After that I will using Native XML Database like exiSt in building that system ...

Comment: What problems are you having with your implementation? In fact, what _is_ your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

1-student information: name address picture birthdae

2-course information: different course like (MCSE , CISCO,MSCD ...)

3-Identical teaching rooms(3 to 5 rooms)

4 - training courses have the same period:

a. Four seasons in each year, 3 months.

b. In each season there are 13 a week.

c. In each season a week there are 3 lots weekly.

d.A class Extends of 3 hours.

e. There are 3 training period per day.

5 - Must the system allows the student to the registration course and is attributable to a class ... Etc..

6 - It is preferable to be building the system so that the browser is the client user.

Comment: @fam: please edit your question to update this information. Do not add a new answer to clarify your question. Also, you'll want to explore your formatting options (see the "how to format" box that appears when you're entering text).

Comment: @fam: also, I asked you about your implementation. You replied with your requirements. Please provide information on your implementation.

Comment: thanx John ...
I edited my question .
I know that i wrote the requirements not implementation, but I want you to help me - such give me link to any useful website you know-,
which contain some similar example that may helped me in writing by myself my project ...